# Angular post request doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, angular

I did a spmple backend in spring with a post that creates a new record in db and I'm trying to call it from frontend.
I'm sure that backend side application works well because I've tested it on postman.
frontend side I have an input where I insert url and a button to create a new record.

My function in service file:

```
addPhoto(url: string) {
        console.log('ciaooo')
        this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/photos/create", {
            url: url
        })
```

My component:

```
  createPhoto() {
    if (!this.formCreate.valid) {
      alert("compilare tutti i campi obbligatori")
    } else {
      //console.log(this.formCreate.controls['url'].value)
      if (this.formCreate.controls['url'].value != null) {
        console.log('hhh')
        let result = this.tservice.addPhoto(this.formCreate.controls['url'].value)
      }else{
        console.log('prop null')
      }
    }
  }
```

my html:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="createPhoto()" [formGroup]="formCreate">
        <input type="text" formControlName='url'>
        <button type="submit">Crea</button>
    </form>
```

I don't receive errors in console. But function hasn't effect

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to the `Observable` returned by `http.post`.

```js
this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/photos/create", {url}).subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned above, you need to subscribe to the `post()` method.

To give some context:
The `post()`, `get()`, `delete()`, etc functions from the `HttpClient` are [RxJS Observables](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable). An Observable is a stream of data. However, the stream is only "flowing" if there is someone listening to it. You listen to a stream by calling the `.subscribe()` function of any Observable.

You could write your `addPhoto` method like this:

```
// Replace unknown with the correct type which is returned from the backend
addPhoto(url: string): Observable<unknown> {
  return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/photos/create", {
      url: url
  })
```

And then update your usage in the component:

```
createPhoto(): void {
  if (!this.formCreate.valid) {
    alert("compilare tutti i campi obbligatori")

    return;
  }

  const urlControlValue: string = this.formCreate.controls['url'].value;
  if (!urlControlValue) {
    return;
  }

  this.tservice.addPhoto(urlControlValue).subscribe((result: unknown) => console.log('result: ', result))
}
```